# How would I replace a value in a 2d array structure for a different value and printing function for the 2d array structure in c?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

The output should print out like this when crew has dig up the whole space of value"s" it changes to value"T" and if you can help create a function for printing the map structure instead of using a for loop every time we'll be greatly appreciated too!:

`Crew   Dig Carry

1       3   1

2       2   5

3       4   1

4       1   3`

Where would you like to send crew member 1?
`4s 1s  3s

1s  2s  3s

1s  5s  1s`

1 3

You have removed all the sand from this section!

Where would you like to send crew member 2?
`4s 1s  1T

1s  2s  3s

1s  5s  1s`

2 2

What I have so far:
    `#include <stdio.h>`
    `#include <stdlib.h>`
    `#include <string.h>`

```
#define NUMCREW 4    
#define MAXHOUR 8    
#define MINHOUR 1    
#define ROW 3    
#define COL 3    


struct pirate {
    int dig;
    int carry;
};  

struct map {
    int sand;
    int treasure;
};

void printcrew(struct pirate * pirate_data);  
void print(struct map * map_data);    


int main() {
char filename[20];
int hour=8;
int crew=0;
int i, j, x, y;
int space;
struct map map_data[ROW][COL];
struct pirate pirate_data[NUMCREW];
FILE * ifp;

printf("You have arrived at Treasure Island!\n");
printf("What is the name of your map?\n");
scanf("%s", filename);

ifp = fopen(filename, "r");



for (i=0; i<ROW; i++){
    for (j=0; j<COL; j++) {
        fscanf(ifp, "%d %d", &map_data[i][j].sand, &map_data[i][j].treasure);
    }
}


for (i=0; i<NUMCREW; i++) {
    fscanf(ifp, "%d", &pirate_data[i].dig);
    fscanf(ifp, "%d", &pirate_data[i].carry);
}

fclose(ifp);
for (hour=8; hour >= MINHOUR; hour--) {
    printf("\nYou have %d hours left to dig up the treasure.\n", hour);
    printcrew(pirate_data);
    printf("\n");

    for (crew=0; crew<NUMCREW; crew++){
        printf("Where would you like to send crew member %d?\n", crew+1);

        for(i=0; i<ROW; i++) {
            for (j=0; j<COL; j++) {
            printf("%ds\t", map_data[i][j].sand);
                if (map_data[i][j].sand == 0) {
                    printf("%dT\t", map_data[i][j].treasure);
            }
        }
            printf("\n");
            }
            scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
            map_data[x-1][y-1].sand = map_data[x-1][y-1].sand - pirate_data[crew].dig;
        }
    }

return 0;
}

void printcrew(struct pirate * pirate_data) {
int i;`

printf("Crew \t Dig \t Carry \n");
for (i=0; i<NUMCREW; i++)
    printf("%d \t %d \t %d \n", i+1, pirate_data[i].dig, pirate_data[i].carry);

return;

}

void print(struct map * map_data) {
int i, j;

for(i=0; i<ROW; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<COL; j++) {
        printf("%ds\t", map_data[i][j].sand);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

return;
```

}

My output keeps coming out like:
Where would you like to send crew member 1?
    `4s      1s      3s

     1s      2s      3s

     1s      5s      1s`
1 3
Where would you like to send crew member 2?
   `4s      1s      0s      1T

     1s      2s      3s

     1s      5s      1s`
2 2
Where would you like to send crew member 3?
    `4s      1s      0s      1T

     1s      0s      1T      3s

     1s      5s      1s`

As for the printing the struct map function I keep getting the following error:
In function 'print':|
error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector|

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a typo in the posted code; there is a stray ` character in the `printcrew()` function. A compiler warning should be seen for this, and all compiler warnings should be fixed.

```
int i;`
```

Concerning the problem with the `print()` function, the function prototype is wrong. In most expressions, function calls included, arrays decay to pointers to their first elements. Now, a 2d array like `struct map map_data[ROW][COL]` is actually an array of `ROW` arrays of `COL` elements. That is, each row of this array has type `struct map map_data[COL]`. When pointer decay occurs, the result is a pointer to the first element, which is a pointer to an array (not a pointer to a `map` `struct`). The syntax for expressing such a pointer to an array is: `struct map (*ptr)[COL]`. So, the function prototype should be:

```
void print(struct map (*map_data)[COL]);
```

To fix the problem with updating the display to show found treasure, check to see if treasure was found *before* printing sand, and only print sand if treasure was not found:

```
for(i=0; i<ROW; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<COL; j++) {
        int sand = map_data[i][j].sand;
        if (sand > 0) {
            printf("%ds\t", sand);
        } else {
            printf("%dT\t", map_data[i][j].treasure);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

A few comments about input validation are in order. Always specify maximum widths when reading string input using the `%s` or `%[]` directives with `scanf()` family functions; failure to do so can lead to buffer overflow and undefined behavior.

Note that `scanf()` and family return the number of successful assignments made; this value should be checked to ensure that input was as expected. In the posted code, if a user slyly signals end-of-file from the keyboard, `scanf()` returns without making an assignment. Since `filename[]` is uninitialized, this leads to undefined behavior when `filename` is used. Instead, try something like:

```
if (scanf("%19s", filename) < 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Input error\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

It is also vitally important to verify that attempts to open files succeed. When files fail to open while code continues as if they opened successfully, undefined behavior follows. `fopen()` returns a null pointer on failure:

```
ifp = fopen(filename, "r");
if (ifp == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file %s\n", filename);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

The moral to this story is that you should check values returned from any function which returns a meaningful value.

There is further potential for trouble due to failure to validate input here:

```
scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
map_data[x-1][y-1].sand = map_data[x-1][y-1].sand - pirate_data[crew].dig;
```

If the user enters non-numeric input, no value is stored in the associated variable. At best this leads to surprising behavior due to use of a previously stored value. At worst this leads to undefined behavior when the value of the associated variable is indeterminate (e.g. uninitialized). Further, the user may enter a non-positive number here, leading to negative array indices and undefined behavior. Or the user may enter too-large values, leading to attempted out-of-bounds array access and undefined behavior. Also, the `sand` member is decremented even when negative; this may or may not be desirable, but could lead to undefined behavior with signed integer overflow for unlikely combinations of industrious pirates and malicious users.

Validate all input, especially user input which is never to be trusted and always to be considered as malicious. Check the value returned by `scanf()` to be sure that input is at least roughly as expected, and check that the input values are within acceptable ranges. How bad input is handled is up to the programmer; one option is to prompt again for correct input:

```
while (scanf("%d %d", &x, &y) < 2
       || x < 1
       || x > COL
       || y < 1
       || y > ROW) {
    printf("Please enter numbers in the ranges [1, %d] [1, %d]\n",
           ROW, COL);
}
map_data[x-1][y-1].sand = map_data[x-1][y-1].sand - pirate_data[crew].dig;
```